# using PHP script for sorting sql database entries

Tags: php, html, sql, sorting

I need some help sorting my score value's of my sql database

```
    <table border = '2'>
    <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo "Could not establish connection to the database " . mysql_error();
    }

    $mydb = mysql_select_db("users", $con);
    if (!$mydb)
    {
        echo "Error selecting database " . mysql_error();
    }

    $mystatement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");
    $dbcount = mysql_num_rows($mystatement);
    $selection = array(0 => "");
    $nameselection = array(0 => "");

    $i = 0; 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mystatement))
        {
        $selection[$i] = $row['score'];
        $nameselection[$i] = $row['username']; 
        //echo "<tr> <td>$row[username]</td> <td>$row[score]</td></tr>";
        $i++; 
        }
arsort($selection);
ksort($nameselection);

for ($x = 0; $x < $dbcount; $x++)
{
    echo "<tr> <td>$nameselection[$x]</td> <td>$selection[$x]</td> </tr>"; 
}


    ?>

    </table>
```

im trying to post the user's scores from my game to a table, sorting them from highest to lowest. I'm just stuck..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$mystatement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");
```

To

```
$mystatement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY score DESC");
```

Remove the array sort

```
arsort($selection);
ksort($nameselection);
```

Comment: beautiful, i'm new to sql, didn't even know you could do that. thank you VERY much

Comment: A [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tutorial.html) can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) in SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$mystatement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY score DESC");
```

Comment: +1 even though you were third to answer, you were first to include the correct fieldname, `score`

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them DB-side using "Order by"

ie. `SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY scores desc`